# Select number of rows between 2 dates

Tags: sql-server

I have two dates ex:('Jan 1 2016' and  'Jan 10 2016')

how can I select number of rows between these dates

like:
        dates

```
     jan 1

     jan 2

     jan 2
     ...
     jan 10
```

thanks..

Comment: If you need how many dates are between the the Jan 1st and Jan 10th, use DATEDIFF function. If you need to count rows in a table where some date attribute is between the two dates, use SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE somedate BETWEEN firstdate AND seconddate. And pls learn how to ask question so people can actually answer it.

Comment: thanks for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a tally  / number table

```
select date = dateadd(day, n, '20160101')
from   number n  -- <= tally / number table
where  n.n >= 0
and    n.n < datediff(day, '20160101', '20160110')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
select * from tableName where columnname>='2016-01-01' and columnname<='2016-01-10'
```